# CSV parser in Go breaks due to trailing space

Tags: csv, go

We are trying to parse a csv file using Go's encoding/csv package. This particular csv is a bit peculiar, each row has a trailing space. When trying to decode this csv with quoted fields the package breaks since it expects a newline, separator or quote. The trailing space is not expected.

How would you handle this case? Do you know of another parser that we could use?

Edit:

```
f,err := os.Open("file.go")
// err etc..
csvr := csv.NewReader(f)
csvr.Comma = csvDelimiter
for {
   rowAsSlice, err := csvr.Read()
   // Handle row and errors etc.
}
```

Edit 2:
CSV example, mind the trailing space!

```
"RECORD_TYPE","COMPANY_SHORTNAME" 
"HDR","COMPANY_EXAMPLE"
```

Comment: No there is no need for another parser you just to remove trailing spaces from each parsed line. Please post the code you have tried for us to regenerate the issue.

Comment: `input = strings.Replace(input, " \n", "\n", -1)`.  Effectively removes the trailing space on each line.  If the last line ends with a space and not a new line, simply follow this call with `input = strings.TrimSpace(input)`.

Comment: Please, include some example code in your question what you have tried.

Comment: Added some code, the issue is that we don't read the file line by line. We let the csv-package handle that.. We probably have to change tactic and handle the lines ourselves and only let the csv package parse the rows into a slice.

Comment: @Vejto Please add some csv sample of your file so that we can parse the file by removing trailing spaces and tabs.

Comment: Added csv sample.

Comment: What does it mean that it breaks ? Are you getting an error ? Did the code panic ? Do you read unexpoected values (if so what did you read and what did you expect )?

Comment: I just found it also chokes on lines like `"foo" ,"bar"` (i.e., a space before the comma separator.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to wrap the source file reader in a custom reader whose `Read(...)` method silently trims trailing whitespace from what the underlying reader actually reads. The `csv.Reader` could use that type directly.

For example ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/HjaUYNakq3S)):

```
type TrimReader struct{ io.Reader }

var trailingws = regexp.MustCompile(` +\r?\n`)

func (tr TrimReader) Read(bs []byte) (int, error) {
  // Perform the requested read on the given reader.
  n, err := tr.Reader.Read(bs)
  if err != nil {
    return n, err
  }

  // Remove trailing whitespace from each line.
  lines := string(bs[:n])
  trimmed := []byte(trailingws.ReplaceAllString(lines, "\n"))
  copy(bs, trimmed)
  return len(trimmed), nil
}

func main() {
  file, err := file.Open("myfile.csv")
  // TODO: handle err...

  csvr := csv.NewReader(TrimReader{file})

  for {
    record, err := csvr.Read()
    if err == io.EOF {
      break
    }
    fmt.Printf("LINE: record=%#v, err=%v\n", record, err)
  }
  // LINE: record=[]string{"RECORD_TYPE", "COMPANY_SHORTNAME"}, err=<nil>
  // LINE: record=[]string{"HDR", "COMPANY_EXAMPLE"}, err=<nil>
}
```

Note that, as commenter @svsd points out, there is a subtle bug here wherein trailing whitespace can still make it through if the line terminator isn't read until the subsequent call. You can workaround by buffering or, perhaps best, simply preprocess these CSV files to remove the trailing whitespace before attempting to parse them.

Comment: This can fail for the edge case where the last byte read was a space but there was a new line just after that, which will be read as the first character in the next Read().

Comment: @svsd hmm yes, great catch. To workaround this implementation would probably want to detect trailing whitespace in the trimmed byte array, omit it, and prepend it to the subsequent read so the same replacement logic can apply. But I'll leave that (or a better solution) as an exercise to the reader =P

Comment: I like the idea! It is quite clean but yeah will look into the edge case. Thanks